# jQuery UI Autocomplete: set active item

Tags: combobox, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to micmic teh behaviour of a simple HTML SELECT element with jQuery Ui Autocomplete.

Is it possible to set the active item (move focus) on the open event? Basically, I am trying to mimic the selected="selected" option from a html select element - if the value in the field matches with one from the list, make that list item 'selected'.

Comment: What are you missing from this example: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: When I select something from the list, for example Clojure - the list will be closed and when I open it again, Clojure is not selected, it looks exactly like every other item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally figured out the answer with the help of a friend.

```
$('input[data-field=vat_rate]', view.el).autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        response(your_source_array);
    },
    minLength: 0,
    open: function (event, ui) {
        var term = ui.item.value;
        if (typeof term !== 'undefined') {
            $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.activate(new $.Event("mouseover"), $('li[data-id=' + term + ']'));
        }
    }
}).click(function () {
    if ($(this).autocomplete('widget').is(':visible')) {
        $(this).autocomplete('close');
    } else {
        $(this).autocomplete('search');
    }
}).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    var listItem = $("<li></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .attr("data-id", item.id)
        .append('<a>' + item.label + '</a>')
        .appendTo(ul);
};
```

Here's the JSBin for it: http://jsbin.com/unibod/2/edit#javascript

Works perfect! :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a jsfiddle of what you'e looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/fordlover49/NUWJr/

Basically, took the [combobox example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox) from jquery's website, and changed the renderItem functionality.   In the example off of jqueryui.com's site, change:

```
   input.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
                return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
   };
```

To:

```
   input.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        $item = $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>");
        if (this.element.val() === item.value) {
            $item.addClass('ui-state-hover');
        }

        return $item.appendTo(ul);
   };
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, it does _almost_ what I want - except that when I open the list with keyboard and try to navigate, it starts from the top of the list, not from the "active" one. However, I already found a solution I'm gonna post here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the `focus` event](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-focus) to add/remove the active class. I like it more than the other `._renderItem` code on this thread.

```
[...previous autocomplete options]
focus: function( event, ui ) {
        // Remove the hover class from all results
        $( 'li', ui.currentTarget ).removeClass('ui-state-hover');

        // Add it back in for results
        $( 'li',ui.currentTarget ).filter(function(index, element) {

        // Only where the element text is the same as the response item label
        return $(element).text() === ui.item.label;
    }).addClass('ui-state-hover');
},
[next autocomplete options...]
```

Comment: thats awesome @zack i just waisted my two to three hours as i was creating custom ui for it using jquery tag editor autocomplete plugin.